# Separate mouse for debugger

Tags: delphi, debugging

I am programming a Delphi (XE3) application where mouse position is important, but I would like to be able with another mouse to be able to set breakpoints without moving the primary mouse position.  I may be pressing shift or control in the application I am trying to debug, so alt-tabbing to the IDE and setting a breakpoint with the keyboard keyboard won't work.  Can Windows 7 easily be set up to do this?

Comment: If you need to break debugger on a breakpoint in certain condition (e.g. break when you're on a certain mouse position in your application), use [`conditional breakpoints`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Setting_and_Modifying_Breakpoints#To_create_a_conditional_breakpoint). What you're describing would need to have 2 mouse cursors in Windows, what I've never seen (even after few beers :-).

Comment: You could use Remote Debugger (if it's available and works) so you can install your program on one computer and the IDE on the other. What you require is otherwise very unusual and can probably worked around; provide more details so we can suggest workarounds.

Comment: Although it is possible to have more than one mouse connected to Windows, there is only one mouse cursor.

Comment: The easiest way is to use something like Codesite to send informational messages to yourself. You can show things like the current mouse position in a single line, or log actions. It is what I do with my word processing.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to attach multiple keyboards and mice to a computer, and various video games can take advantage of the multiple input devices, but the OS in general does not take advantage of that. No matter how many keyboards and mice you attach, there's still just one input queue and one cursor on the screen.

If all you need is to set breakpoints without moving the mouse, then you can navigate the input caret to the desired line with the keyboard and then press <kbd>F5</kbd> to toggle breakpoints.

If you need to be able to debug without interfering with the program at all, then you might need to **use [remote debugging](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Overview_of_Remote_Debugging)**. Although the documentation suggests using Remote Desktop to operate the remote program while you're sitting at the local system, that's not what you want to do in this situation because you'll still have just one set of input devices. Instead, log on to the remote computer from elsewhere (either directly, or via Remote Desktop on a third computer). It'll help to have two computers you can access from the same chair.

Comment: Also you can use virtual machine + remote debugging.

Comment: If the issue is getting the mouse back to the position it was in before a breakpoint, perhaps you could write yourself two functions to save and restore the mouse cursor position. Put them in a standalone program and have them called by some system-wide hotkeys.

Comment: At present, it sounds like what I have been doing may be the simplest, but often requires recompiling and re-duplicating an issue--that is to insert code that breaks on a keystroke so my mouse position or mousedown isn't compromised.

Comment: You don't need to write your own code to stop on a special key. The OS already has that built in. Just press F12 and the debugger will interrupt your program. [If you're using Windows 7 or later, you might need to install an IDE expert.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13970455/33732)